# Selenium Webdriver & Java: capture image and display it in result page

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

How would you display a screenshot taken via webdriver inside a JSP page (maybe via iframe), as soon as screenshot is taken?

---something like BrowserStack's new feature of displaying screenshot.

Looking for logic.

FYI: right now screenshots are stored in different folder with random Name. So, I was not able to iterate through folder and display them inside a jsp page.

```
public void runWebdriverScript(){
    //run scripts
    //calls takescreenshot(elementInfo, driver)
}

public void takescreenshot(elementInfo, driver){
    //if elementInfo.equals to yes take screen shot
    // Once screenshot taken it should be displayed in a jsp page
}
```

In JSP page:

```
//automatically create following
//using bootstrap
<div class="item">
    <img src="{  add filePath  }" alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption Text</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```